# Retag megaman to mega-man

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I've observed questions in the Mega Man series tagged as the following:

[megaman](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/megaman) [megaman-zx-advent](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/megaman-zx-advent) [street-fighter-x-megaman](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-x-megaman) [mega-man-zx](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mega-man-zx)

However, the proper name is Mega Man, so should these tags be updated to reflect that? Meaning with a `-` to represent the space in the name?

Comment: Sigh. None of the questions tagged mega-man was actually about Mega Man.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure how much of a fan I am of this change. There seem to be quite a few naming inconsistencies now in 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm at least a little worried by the tag length limit as e.g. [street-fighter-x-mega-man](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-x-mega-man) is 25 characters long precisely already. It's a cosmetic change mostly so other than that I don't see why I should decline it.